# How to solve "Keystrokes is not abstract and does not override ab. method"

Tags: java, io

I am a learning Java programming and am trying to compile the below code from a book. When I try to compile the code I get this error

```
Keystrokes is not abstract and does not override abstract method 
    keyTyped (java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener.
```

Also, I believe this is unrelated but the book also told me to add this section of code to the source code(somewhere?):

```
pnl.add ( field) ;
pnl.add (txtArea);
```

When I do I get an Identifier "Expected Error".

The program code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

  class Keystrokes extends JFrame implements KeyListener
  {
   JPanel pnl = new JPanel(); 

  public static void main (String[ ] args){
      Keystrokes gui = new Keystrokes();
    }

    JTextField field = new JTextField ( 38 );
    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea (5, 38);

 public Keystrokes()
    {
     super( "Swing window");
     setSize( 500,200);
     setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     add(pnl);
     field.addKeyListener (this );

     setVisible( true );
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event )
    {
        txtArea.setText("Key Pressed");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void KeyTyped (KeyEvent event ) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        txtArea.append("\nCharacter : " + event.getKeyChar() );
    }

    public void keyReleased ( KeyEvent event) 
    {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
       txtArea.append("\nKey Code : " + event.getKeyCode() );
       textArea.append("\nKey Text : " + event.getKeyText(keyCode));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't include more than one blank line of white-space at a time.  And for the sake of people reading it, as well as debugging, use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `KeyTyped` should be `keyTyped`. Capitalization matters.

Comment: Thanks, i was copying letter for letter from the book

Comment: @Edmund: then either the book or your transcription skills are in error.

Comment: I doubt that.  The author of that book would be smacking you in the head right now if s/he were here.

Comment: any input on my second problem?

Comment: @Edmund: where do you try to put that code? You understand that it must go in a method or constructor, right? that you can't put it just out in the class somewhere.?

Comment: The book didnt say so I assumed it went below "JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea (5, 38);" but I have tried to put it everywhere in the code.

Comment: You need to create a constructor and use it. You need to read up on use of methods and constructors as well.

Comment: @EdmundDoyle I would suggest putting it immediately before `add(pnl)`.

Comment: Look into `@Override` notation.  Very handy for pointing out errors like the compilation error.

Comment: Ask youself: What does `add(field)` do? When is it possible / necessary to do it? Also some advice: group every statement that is not written in any method and don't spread them across the whole code. Better yet: add them to your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Keystrokes is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyTyped (java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener.
```

This means that the `KeyListener` interface that your `Keystrokes` class claims to implement has some other methods that must be implemented, but you failed to do so.  Implement the `keyTyped` method and have a look at the javadocs to see if you missed any others.

That should get you to your next problem.

Comment: I feel so silly... I wrote TextArea instead of "txtArea". Thank's everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive; you named your method KeyTyped instead of the required keyTyped from the base class.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see that this answer was already provided! And I meant interface, not base class...